# #id selectors not working as expected in jQuery and JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align:right" rowspan="1">Total:</th>
    <th id="pktamt" style="text-align:right" class="right_align" rowspan="1" colspan="1">4200.00</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align:right" rowspan="1">Weight :</th>
    <th id="pktwt" style="text-align:right" rowspan="1" colspan="1">21.21</th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Need to read values `4200.00` and `21.21` with id `pktamt` and `pktwt` respectively.

Tried the following :

```
var amt = $("#pktamt").text();  // Notworking
var amt = document.getElementById("pktamt").innerText;  // Notworking
```

Thanks in advance for helping a newbie..

Comment: <tfoot>
                <tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:right" rowspan="1">Total:</th><th id="pktamt" style="text-align:right" class="right_align" rowspan="1" colspan="1">4200.00</th></tr>
                <tr><th colspan="2" style="text-align:right" rowspan="1">Weight :</th><th id="pktwt" style="text-align:right" rowspan="1" colspan="1">21.21</th></tr>
            </tfoot>

Comment: They work both as shown in this Fiddle (open the console): https://jsfiddle.net/h0gfw4a7/1/ Also don't put your code as comment but into the question, you can edit it anytime.

Comment: Make sure you include the proper jQuery before you try the first statement. Having said that also please make sure that there are no errors in browser's `console` before you execute those statement because wherever in a JS file an error is encountered the rest of the JS doesn't work as the above statements work as @matthias_h showed in example.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies. Butremains unresolved. Checked for errors in browser console there are nil. console.log(amt); gives 0.00 in console.     $(document).ready(function () {
    
    var id = $('#grade_id').val(); issue // working as expected

    loadDataTable(id); // working as expected

    var amt = $("#pktamt").text(); // not working as expected
    var wt = document.getElementById("pktwt").innerText;  // not working as expected
    
    console.log(amt);
    console.log(wt);
    $("#amount").val("4200");
    $("#weight").val("21.21");
   
});

Comment: So is `loadDataTable(id);` loading the elements you are trying to read? My guess is it is and the data is not there

Comment: There is data checked in inspect DataTable is doing as expected. It is after DataTable  is loaded from HTML need to read 2 cells in footer row 0 and row 1 Even tried var amt1 = $('tfoot:eq(0) tr:eq(0) th:eq(1)').text();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `<tfoot>` is direct child of `<table>` tag.
`<tfoot>` element wont parse by DOM if it isn't inside  tag

## EDIT

I've added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AymanAli/a5kv1odb/4/) contains a working markup. Jquery 1.12

On your web browser after you open your html page you can right click on any area and click on "**Inspect**" option there you will find a tab labeled "**Console**"
you can always test your scripts there and check for errors.

Scripts tag for reading elements on DOM must be after the element been rendered "at the end of body tag is a good place for them"

Comment: Checked that too

Comment: var amt1 = $('tfoot:eq(0) tr:eq(0) th:eq(1)').text(); Tried this too but gives zero value.